# Como alterar um documento HTML 4 para HTML 5?

Tags: html, html5, doctype

Eu tenho um projeto já pronto, feito em HTML 4.01, como eu posso alterar para que ele reconheça HTML 5 ?

Eu posso só alterar isso:

```
 < !DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd" >
```

por:

```
< !DOCTYPE html >
```

e irá funcionar ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exatamente, esta é a forma correta. Esta forma torna o código compatível com HTML 5 e com versões anteriores.

- [Especificação](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/).
- [Artigo](http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-doctype/) sobre a vantagem desta forma simples.

Eu só não gosto dos espaços na abertura e fechamento da *tag*, mas é gosto mesmo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: ba, legal. Valeu.