# Qual doctype utilizar em um documento html?

Tags: html5

Galera estou fazendo um curso on line e a primeira Tag que apareceu na linha de digitação foi essa para html, sei que já está na versão 5 e inclusive  já surgiram outros tipos de tags. Abri essa questão por curiosidade. É realmente necessário usar esta tag `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` na abertura da linguagem em HTML ou podemos apenas utilizar `<!DOCTYPE HTM>`?

Comment: Relacionadas: [Como alterar um documento HTML 4 para HTML 5?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/58613/91) e [Declaração DOCTYPE do HTML](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/150944/91)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No HTML5 você utilizará apenas `<!DOCTYPE html>`, não há a necessidade de validação. Ou seja, `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` é utilizada por causa da validação da linguagem XML que a exige em arquivos XHTML.

Answer (score 0):

Em HTML5 usamos apenas `<!DOCTYPE html>` e é necessário para informar aos navegadores que aquele arquivo é um HTML.