# Dúvida sobre tags DOCTYPE e HTML

Tags: html, doctype

Há muitos anos venho usando estas tags no início das minhas páginas:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Esse código fui herdando ao longo do tempo desde muitos anos atrás e sempre mantive nas páginas, e nunca tive problemas.

Hoje me deparei com uma mensagem de alerta no console do IE (Windows 10, IE11):

```
HTML1524: HTML5 DOCTYPE inválido. Convém usar o formato interoperável "<!DOCTYPE html>".
```

Afinal, devo excluir essa linha com `!DOCTYPE` ou altera-la? A tag `<html>` devo manter como está ou deixar apenas `<html>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deve alterá-la, a tag `<!DOCTYPE html>` indica ao navegador que o documento Html deve ser lido como um **HTML5**, assim como está [documentado na W3C](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#doctype-declaration).

> O @Maniero responde a uma pergunta sobre a "**[Declaração do DOCTYPE do HTML](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/150945/45722)**", acredito que pode ajudar a ter mais informações.

Quanto ao `xmls` na sua tag `html`, tem uma pergunta e resposta sobre isto também: [Quando usar o atributo xmlns no elemento html?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/119348/quando-usar-o-atributo-xmlns-no-elemento-html/119800)

> Segundo a resposta (um resumo breve) o uso do `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` indica que a sintaxe utilizada no documento é na verdade **XHTML5** e não **HTML5**.

Para dúvida em como manter compatibilidade com versões anteriores, recomendo está pergunta: [Como alterar um documento HTML 4 para HTML 5](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58613/como-alterar-um-documento-html-4-para-html-5)?

> Também segundo a resposta, a tag `<!DOCTYPE html>` *"torna o código compatível com HTML 5 e com versões anteriores"*.

Recomendo também ver: [É correto omitir a start tag html no HTML5?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/120134/%C3%89-correto-omitir-a-start-tag-html-no-html5)

Comment: Só o oro mano. Obg!

Comment: E a parada do `<html>`?

Comment: @dvd Adicionei a resposta :)

Comment: @dvd Acredito que se o que você pretende é utilizar HTML5 ao invés de XHTML5, deve removê-la.

Comment: Devo deixar somente `<html>`?

Comment: @dvd Encontrei algo a respeito, aqui no SOpt também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58613/como-alterar-um-documento-html-4-para-html-5?rq=1

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72029/discussion-between-vinicius-lima-and-dvd).

Comment: Não po. É que eu não entendo muito de doctype.